# How to fix import error called by connected-react-router module?

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-router, connected-react-router

I'm confused by issue caused by react-router-dom. It can't import matchPath function from react-router. Exception is:

./node_modules/connected-react-router/esm/selectors.js
Attempted import error: 'matchPath' is not exported from 'react-router'.

Comment: there is no such a thing as `matchPath` in react router. `match` and `history` are part of the props passed to component if you have wrapped your app with Routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matchPath was added to react-router sometime after V3.2.1 and before V4.3.1.
Check which version you have with:

```
npm list react-router
```

If it's an older (v3) than update it with:

```
npm update react-router
```